# How to tune a wildcard search of text column?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, full-text-search

I need some help with wildcard search with % operator at both ends. The table has  nearly 7 million records.

Is there any option to create an index for this? I already created an index of index type CTXSYS which works well for single % operator at one end.
Please help.

Comment: Can you attach the query?

Comment: You need to check this first:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Text doesn't work with the `%` wildcard operator - that's for `LIKE`. Have you created a CONTEXT or CTXCAT index? What kind of data are you indexing - big docs? text snippets? names? Which version of Oracle?

Comment: what is the CTXSYS index type? anybody?

Comment: query is quite simple-
select item_number from md_sku_table where item_number like '%TEST%';

I need to use % operator with just varchar field of 50 Bytes size.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break each stored string value out into a text field that contains every permutation that could be searched against.  You can then index this text field and do "contains" searches which will be much more efficient than wildcard.

See this article for a detailed example.  https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:37336026927381

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created CONTEXT type text index on item_number. Here is the syntax -

```
SELECT item_number FROM md_sku_table WHERE CONTAINS(item_number, 'TEST', 1) > 0;
```

As suggested above, you should not use LIKE '%%' here ...